# Assign the SRID to a serialized GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, geodjango, serialize

I've created a simple model like this:

```
class AddPoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom = geomodels.PointField(srid=3857)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

With this view I export the db contents as GeoJSON:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

def addPointGeoJson(request):
    vectors = serialize(
        'geojson',
        AddPoint.objects.all(),
        )
    content_type = 'json'
    return HttpResponse(vectors, content_type)
```

When I see the exported GeoJSON the SRID is not 3857 but 4326. Why happen this?

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "Napoli", "publishing_date": "2019-07-27T18:12:36.831", "updating_date": "2019-07-27T18:12:36.843", "timestamp": "2019-07-27T18:12:36.843", "pk": "30"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [14.291931129992006, 40.84290487729676]}}]}
```

I know that [GeoJSON Serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/#module-django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson) use 4326 as default SRID but 
I expected it to change to 3857 as in the model.

Comment: GeoJSON isn't valid GeoJSON unless it uses longitude,latitude pairs.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: GeoJson standard deprecated CRS tag, and the only standard compliant coordinate system is 4326.

Comment: Here there are the specification and I read that the crs is necessary https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#coordinate-reference-system-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better thing is use [django-rest-framework-gis](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis) for serialize a GeoJSON.
Moreover [the SR of a GeoJSON is 4326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-4) as indicated on official guide and

> In general, GeoJSON    processing software is not expected to have
> access to coordinate    reference system databases or to have network
> access to coordinate    reference system transformation parameters

Answer (score 1):

Pass SRID as option in serialize

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

def addPointGeoJson(request):
    vectors = serialize(
        'geojson',
        AddPoint.objects.all(),
        srid= 'EPSG:3857',
        )
    content_type = 'json'
    return HttpResponse(vectors, content_type)
```

`

Comment: For me was not clear that SRID must be put after the query. I've already tried to put it inside the serialize but before `AddPoint.objects.all()` and I seen an error: `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: I've noticed a trouble with your solution. Now `addPointGeoJson` give `%d format: a number is required, not str`